# whatever / what ever happened to the Unknown Comic?

Tags: grammar

Should "whatever" be one or two words in the sentence below?

Whatever / What ever happened to the Unknown Comic?

If one word or two words, why?

Thank you.

Comment: It can be either.

Comment: Which is preferred -- the one- or two-word rendering?

Comment: In my experience, the one word version is preferred. The two word version is a bit more old fashioned (or stilted, or formal, or something in that vein). Though the two word version *does* let you emphasize "ever" more, if you want to really stress your curiosity.